# How to flatten keyed collections to an array in Laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel

Currently, I have a result from a query like this (Using orWhere):

```json
[{"mainPos":"LW","secondaryPos":"CAM","tertiaryPos":null},
{"mainPos":"ST","secondaryPos":"LW","tertiaryPos":null}]
```

which I want to convert to this:

```php
["LW", "CAM", "ST"]
```

To do this, I can break the process down into three parts:

```
1. Flatten Array
[{...},{...}] -> ["LW", "CAM", null, "ST", "LW", null]

2. Remove null objects
3. Remove duplicates
```

I can do steps 2-3, but the first one has been hard. I've tried

```php
$collection->flatten(1);
$collection->values();
$collection->values()->all();
```

But they don't modify the original result at all.

Comment: "But they don't modify the original result at all." That's right. From the documentation, `Furthermore, almost every method returns a new Collection instance, allowing you to preserve the original copy of the collection when necessary`. You need to assign the result to a new variable.

Comment: `$collection = $collection->flatten(1);`

Comment: @waterloomatt I assigned the collections to a new variable.

Comment: @V-K Doesn't work either when I assign it to a new variable.

Comment: can you add the result output?

Comment: This is for you, hope you like it https://rextester.com/DNB40203

Comment: @V-K It's same to the original output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use PHP's builtin **[RecursiveIteratorIterator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursiveiteratoriterator.php)** Class :

```
$a = '[{"mainPos":"LW","secondaryPos":"CAM","tertiaryPos":null}, {"mainPos":"ST","secondaryPos":"LW","tertiaryPos":null}]';
$a = json_decode($a, true);  // make json to a php array
$it = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($a));
$x = []; 
foreach($it as $v) {
   $x[] = $v;
}
$x = array_unique($x);
$x = array_filter($x);
print_r($x);
```

Above code tested **[here](https://rextester.com/DNB40203)**

Answer (score 1):

You can try this solution

```
$colelction = $collection->flatten()->filter(function ($elem) {
                  return $elem;
              })->unique();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is also a more straightforward solution:

```
$json_data = '[{"mainPos":"LW","secondaryPos":"CAM","tertiaryPos":null},
{"mainPos":"ST","secondaryPos":"LW","tertiaryPos":null}]';

$array_data = json_decode($arr, true);

$payload = array_map(function ($item) {

            if ($item) return array_flip(array_filter($item));

        }, $array_data);

$result = array_keys(array_merge(...$payload));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$a = '[{"mainPos":"LW","secondaryPos":"CAM","tertiaryPos":null}, {"mainPos":"ST","secondaryPos":"LW","tertiaryPos":null}]';

$a = json_decode($a, true);      

$x = []; 
foreach($a as $v) {
    $x[] = $v['mainPos'];
    $x[] = $v['secondaryPos'];
}

$x = array_filter(array_unique($x));

print_r($x);
```

Live Demo
https://rextester.com/MPG50320

Comment: if `tertiaryPos` is not null, then?